# PDO : Login Validation

Tags: php, validation, pdo, authentication

After looking around here and there I managed to create a simple login. I can login with my user id and password but unfortunately, the login validation doesn't work. When I entered a wrong password or left the textfield empty and clicked login, the form will only be reseted. It doesn't show the error message. I'm sure I'm missing something but I've no clue what it is.

Please help me. Thank you :)

Here's my code :

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$conn = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','root','');

if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $UserId = $_POST['UserId'];
    $UserPwd = $_POST['UserPwd'];


if(empty($UserId) && empty($UserPwd)) {
    $message = "Username/Password con't be empty";
    } 
        else 
            {
            $sql = "SELECT UserId, UserPwd FROM user WHERE UserId=? AND UserPwd=? ";
            $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(array($UserId,$UserPwd));

        if($query->rowCount() >= 1) {
            $_SESSION['UserId'] = $UserId;
            header("location: login.php");
            } 
            else 
                {
                $message = "Username/Password is wrong";
            }
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head><title>Login</title></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="login">
            <input type="text" name="UserId">
            <input type="text" name="UserPwd">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hii you just forget to echo your `$message`. That's why you are not getting any message.

declare your message at top of page

```
$message = "";   

 <html>
        <head><title>Login</title></head>
        <body>
            <span><?php echo $message?></span>// echo your message here
            <form method="post" name="login">
                <input type="text" name="UserId">
                <input type="text" name="UserPwd">
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```